# Exception Handling for specific condition - Best Practice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, exception

I have following code in DAO method :

```
public void someMethod() throws CustomException {
       try {
           ... do something ...
        }catch(Exception e) {
             if(e.getCause() instanceOf org.hibernate.ConstraintViolationException && e.getMessage().contains("child record found")) {
                  throw new CustomException("Child records found.");
             }else {
                  throw new CustomException("Unable to update.");
             }
        }
}
```

In service layer :

```
public void someMethod() throws CustomException {
 dao.someMethod();
}
```

And in Controller :

```
public ResponseObject someMethod() {
  ResponseObject response = new ResponseObject();
  try {
    service.someMethod();
    response.setMessage("success");
  }catch(CustomException e) {
    response.setMessage(e.getMessage());
  }
  return response;
}
```

Am I going correctly as per BEST PRACTICES ?
What else I can do to make it proper ?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: "Best practice" questions are better asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I noticed.  First, use exceptions only for exceptional conditions.   Put another way, exceptions should be the exception, not the norm.  From what it looks like, "ConstraintViolationException" is something that is going to be expected a lot.
Exceptions make the code uglier, harder to debug, and reduce JVM optimizations that greatly speed up program execution.

Second, you should only use checked exceptions (exceptions that don't extend from RuntimeException) if the caller can be reasonable expected to recover.  In your case, the caller doesn't do anything to recover except give the client an error message. 
By throwing a checked exception, you force the caller to handle the exception in a catch clause or propagate it outwards.  (Both are these pitfalls are detailed in Joshua Bloch's excellent book, "Effective Java".)

Third, in your exception handling, you try to parse the error message.  This can be very problematic because third parties often change their error messages, because they
are not a part of the API.  Once this happens, you're code is broken.  Another minor problem in your exception handling is that tie your JPA implementation to hibernate.  What if later you want to change to EclipseLink?

There is a way to address all these issues.
Get rid of the exception handling in your DAO.
Add the following method to your DAO:

```
boolean childRecordExists(Record record)
```

Then, in your controller, have something like:

```
if (service.childRecordExists()){
   response.setMessage("Failed.  A child record exists");  //a useful error message for the user, as you know *exactly* why failure happened
} else {
    service.someMethod();
    response.setMessage("Success");
}
```

You will need some sort of exceptionHandler in the controller.  (If you're using Spring MVC, you can just add it as another method using the ExceptionHandler annotation.)
This would address things that are truly exceptions (things that are out of the ordinary for the everyday user experience, and things that the user can't fix.)

Comment: OP specifically speaks of spring - all spring Exceptions are unchecked. More, by default, the transactional layer of Spring uses the occurence of an unchecked exception to decide to rollback the transaction. I'm not sure the advice not to use unchecked exception is appropriate in this context.